# Java TimerTask wait for last task

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timertask

Consider the following example:

```
// Helper constructor
public Timer(final TimerTask action, final long interval)
{
    scheduleAtFixedRate(action, 0, interval);
}

... (different class)

private Timer myTimer;

public void start()
{
    myTimer = new Timer(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            doStuff(); <<----------------------------
        }                                           |
    }, 10);                                         |
}                                                   |
                                                    |
public void stop()                                  |
{                                                   |
    myTimer.cancel();                               |
    myTimer.purge();                                |
    doMoreStuff(); // << may not be called while doStuff is running!
}
```

doStuff() does something that takes time. I must wait until doStuff has finished if any is running before I want to continue with doMoreStuff.

Is there any (legal) way of adding a waitUntilFinished method that I can use here or should I just copy'n'paste the java.util.Timer class to my own and implement the method myself?

Answer (score 0):

TimerTask is supposed to be asynchronous.

You need to properly implement thread management.
Using a Executors or a thread pool to monitor the tasks execution life cycle.

Comment: Depends on if they are asynchronous.
Does doMoreStuff(), depend on doStuff() being complete?

Comment: doMoreStuff() closes some Closeables that doStuff() uses... so in simple terms, yes it depends on doStuff() not running any more and never running again

Comment: Why use timertask? timertask is supposed to execute every n interval?
Why not a plain runnable that is executed once?

Again timerTask and runnable are designed to be "easy to use" asynchronous(i.e i don't care about the order or when they complete ) thread implementations.

Comment: because doStuff must be executed every 0.01 seconds. it is a task that must be executed on a different thread with a 10 milliseconds interval that must stop when "stop()" is called and stop() must wait for any running doStuff() invocations before it is allowed to return

Comment: Again to implement this properly you need to use a thread pool.
Thus if you have the N number of doStuff() executing you can check the thread pool and wait for or cancel for each thread currently executing.

Comment: There will only be one thread executing doStuff if that makes it easier. If I can get a Thread object it would be much easier, but when I search for "java run thread every x seconds" then I just get redirected to timertasks or the concurrent lib Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()... which seems to provide this functionality but I have no idea how it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an explicit lock.

The task needs to acquire a lock in order to `doStuff()`, and backs off once it cannot get the lock, in fact, it'll never try to `doSuff()` ever again.

The `stop()` method will cancel the `Timer` and lock. It will block until it gets the lock, so if `doStuff()` is going on, it'll have to wait. Once it has the lock, it explicitly disables the task, so that after releasing the lock, a remaining run of the task will not try to doStuff() any more.

```
public class TimerStuff {

    private Timer myTimer;
    private Lock lock;
    private ScheduledTask scheduledTask;

    public void start() {
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        myTimer = new Timer();
        scheduledTask = new ScheduledTask(lock);
        myTimer.schedule(scheduledTask, 0, interval);
    }

    public void stop() {
        myTimer.cancel(); // stop the scheduling
        lock.lock(); // if doStuff is busy, we'll block until it's finished, once we have the lock the task cannot doStuff()

        try {
            scheduledTask.disable(); // once we release the lock, the task won't attempt to run again
            doMoreStuff(); // we're certain doStuff() isn't running, and won't run after this
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }

    private void doMoreStuff() {
        //***
    }

}

class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {
    private final Lock lock;
    private volatile boolean mayRun = true;

    public ScheduledTask(Lock lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mayRun = mayRun && lock.tryLock();
        if (mayRun) {
            try {
                doStuff();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public void disable() {
        this.mayRun = false;
    }

    private void doStuff() {
        // ... the stuff
    }


}
```